# Formatting ls -l Output into pipe delimited file

Tags: ls, text-formatting

I am fairly new to Unix and could use some assistance. When I execute the `ls -l` command (actually `ls -alR`) and pipe the output into a file, there are spaces used in separating the ls fields returned. What I am looking to achieve is essentially separating the ls fields by say a Tab or a pipe character (either should work). I began looking at the `pr` command and replaced the spaces with Tabs, but that did not work as there are varying number of spaces in the ls output, which resulted in erroneous fields when importing this file.

Comment: You might consider taking a look at this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/129120/90691  Trying to parse the output of `ls` isn't a great idea.

Comment: What OS are we working with here? One without GNU utilities?

Answer (score 6):

If you going to parse this output later on, I would discourage it.  See [this page](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) for a good description of why.  In any case it's going to be overly difficult to get the information you want using `ls`, especially if there are spaces or other special characters in filenames.  A better option if you just want to build a csv or something is to use the `-printf` option to `find.`  This command should get you started:

```
find . -printf "%M|%n|%u|%s|%P\n" > output
```

Note that this will recurse from the starting directory like your `ls` command.  It dumps the permissions, link count, owner, group, size, and filename to a file with fields separated by pipes.  Check out the man page for `find` for more info.

Comment: Is it possible to pipe the find output into printf as printf is not an option to use with find on the man page.

Comment: Oh, if you're using a version of find without the `printf` option you may have to go with Jeff's answer using `stat`.  Note that his use of `globstar` and `dotglob` are bash specific.

Comment: Are there any other options if the version uses the Korn Shell or have we reached the extent of available options?

Comment: The shell shouldn't matter for this, it's which version of `find` you have.  Since you don't have GNU find or bash, you could try using the `-exec` option of find to run `stat` on each file.

Borrowing from the other answer, you could try this: `find . -exec stat -c "%A|%h|%U|%G|%s|%Y|%n" {} \+ > output`

Note that this includes the relative path of the file in the filename, like `./foo`

Answer (score 3):

Instead of jumping through hoops to parse ls, you could instead *emulate* `ls -l` with the GNU coreutils `stat` command, using a format of your choosing. If you layer on a bash shell for the globstar option to recursively list files and the dotglob option to list dot-files, then you can get pretty reasonable results. For the file modification times, I've chosen to use `%Y`, which is "seconds since the epoch"; you could use `%y`, or even pass the %Y value to `date` to reformat it however you choose. Using seconds-since-the-epoch is a pretty flexible way to let the down-stream processor display it however it likes.

For a simple file:

```
$ stat -c "%A|%h|%U|%G|%s|%Y|%n" hosts.txt
-rw-r--r--|1|username|pgrp|135387|1202230643|hosts.txt
```

To emulate `ls -alR`:

```
$ shopt -s globstar dotglob
$ stat -c "%A|%h|%U|%G|%s|%Y|%n" **
drwxr-xr-x|2|username|pgrp|4096|1510073497|.dotdir
-rw-r--r--|1|username|pgrp|0|1510073497|.dotdir/.dotfile
-rw-r--r--|1|username|pgrp|0|1507213776|f/test case
-rw-r--r--|1|username|pgrp|0|1507213776|f/test case.csv
-rw-r--r--|1|username|pgrp|135387|1202230643|hosts.txt
drwxr-xr-x|2|username|pgrp|4096|1510073307|space dir
-rw-r--r--|1|username|pgrp|0|1510073307|space dir/space file
-rwxr-xr-x|1|username|pgrp|112|1510073163|stat.sh
```

While this may be less portable (to systems that don't have coreutils / stat), it does have the benefit of being flexible with printing only the fields that you're interested in, and doesn't risk replacing spaces in filenames.

Answer (score 0):

simply add following:

```
ls -alR |  sed -r s'/\s+/|/g'
```

this should work for any command whose output you would like to modify.
\s stands for "space" the "+" stands for one or more occurences (so it would match tab" then the "|" is the symbol which we'd use for the new separator. Please bare in mind that there are some special characters which should be escaped with "\".
if you like tabs, here it is:

```
 ls -alR |  sed -r s'/\s+/\t/g'
```

Comment: Will fail for a file called `file name`.

Comment: Thanks George. When executing this I received an error that -r is an illegal option. Is this referring to the sed subcommand rather than a flag? What would that look like to execute? Regards

Comment: DopeGhoti - Is there a method I can use to ignore spaces once it reaches the file names?

Comment: maybe I had to pay attention to the "UNIX" you mentioned. Do you really work with any UNIX flavor or it is a kind of Linux? In the former, chances are your version of sed does not support regular expressions.

Comment: Looks like 58 characters until file name starts. So ultimately would only need to replace the space occurrences within the first 58 characters of the output.

Comment: Better idea: don't parse the output of ls.